# removing the h3 closing tag only after getting the source by file_get_contents

Tags: php, html

I am using file_get_contents to get the html source of remote page using the code below :

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "remotesite/static/section35.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo $doc->saveHTML(); // save new HTML
?>
```

what i want do now is to remove every `h3` closing tage `</h3>` from the source before echo it to my page as thos is the only way that the content appear properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo str_replace('</h3>','',$doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: thank u this works well but if I  want to remove only `</h3>` that have `<table` after it how should this done?